# Faster sql query for Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a oracle database with over 2 million rows and 200 columns. I'm trying to query data in five columns where one of the columns is equal to the most recent date. This query below works but seems to be taking long (over 2 min) to process. Is there a different logic I can use to speed up the query?

```
SELECT a,b,c,date,e FROM table a WHERE a.date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM table)
```

Comment: Can you share a SQL Monitor report?

Comment: Perhaps posting the explain plan will help

Comment: Also consider updating the tables stats

Comment: @EdHeal. Yes, but a SQL Monitor report would be better :)

Comment: I was assuming that the person might have the cheaper option

Comment: @EdHeal. How do you know it's a stats problem? Is that a guess??

Comment: I do not know. But table stats effect the optimizer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135805/discussion-between-bobc-and-ed-heal).

Comment: @EdHeal unfortunately, I don't have access to the DBMS. I'm an external user connecting from an app

Comment: Do you have index on `date ` column ?

Comment: Can you connect via `sqldeveloper` and find out?

Comment: If this query is taking over 2 minutes, unless it is over a telephone line or such, it is almost certain (or your client) don't have an index on `date`. Ask them if they can add one. The query should then be very fast, since both accessing the max(date) and accessing the row or the few rows with the max(date) would be done by index and would be very fast.

Comment: @mathguy unless the cardinality is say, 1.8Million. Then an index is bad :)

Comment: @BobC - I am not following. What do you mean?

Comment: @mathguy Supposing there are 1.8 million (out of the 2 million) rows, that satisfy the WHERE condition? Then accessing via an index would not be good. Now hopefully we would have appropriate stats so that the optimizer make the right choice. But where I am going with this, is that I always try to get people to determine root cause, rather than just guess. That way, everyone can learn who to diagnose issues.

Comment: @BobC - Why would you ever expect that 1.8 million rows out of 2 million will all have exactly the same value in the `date` column, equal to `max(date)`? That's the part I am not following.

Comment: "Is there a different logic I can use to speed up the query?" - No.

Comment: @mathguy. Believe me, I've seen it all !! I was just using 1.8 as an example. That fact is that I don't. The fact is that (as far as I know), nobody does - and everyone is guessing. So, lets get the diagnostic data (SQL Monitor preferably, explain plan as the next best option) and see.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the execution. [_Formatted_](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

### try rownum

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT A,B,C,DATE,E FROM TABLE A WHERE A.DATE   DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM=1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use another similar solution

```
with  tbl1 as 
(SELECT A,B,C,DATE,E,
       first_value(date) over( order by date desc) maxdate
   FROM TABLE A)
select A,B,C,DATE,E from tbl1 where date = maxdate
```

Answer (score 0):

YES !!!

Set Index "date" to your table as I_TABLE_DATE, after that change your query to this

```
SELECT --+ index_desc(a I_TABLE_DATE)
    a,b,c,date,e 
FROM table a 
WHERE a.date = (SELECT --+ index_desc(b I_TABLE_DATE)
                b.Date
                FROM table b
                where Rownum = 1)
```

it will be more faster because, during getting maximum date there will be only scanning index by descening, and your main query will work by index ascening and you dont need scan all table